# Partially apply an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

Say I want to create 'desktop-only' and 'mobile-only' directives that hide or show an element based on and env test. There are a dozen ways I could go about it, but a cool one would be to "partially apply" the existing 'ng-show' directive. So 'desktop-only' would be the equivalent of, and actually delegate to, 'ng-show="env.isDesktop"' but without the need to do the env test in some parent controller and put env in my scope.

Another common example would be a tabs plugin. I could write a `tab` directive to show and hide elements using `show` and `hide` jQuery functions, but this would lose a lot of the functionality already in the `ngShow` directive. Couldn't I have my `tab` directive extend the ngShow directive in order to get access to all that variable parsing, integration with ngAnimate, etc...

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could put the results of an environment test into $rootScope, but directive isolate scopes would not be able to access that property (since they don't prototypically inherit from their parents).

Comment: Exactly. So I don't want to do that. And this is a very simple example to illustrate the point. I could come up with other uses for where "extending" or "delegating to" other directives would be useful. A menu that's actually just a popover with the "hideOnMouseOut" is set to true, which is actually just a tooltip with html content, which is actually just a modal with extra positioning tacked on.... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When using isolate scopes you could manually proxy some variables into the scope: `$scope.current.device = $rootScope.current.device;`
Appart from that, you could use the afforementioned approach to put a `device` model on `$rootScope` and have methods and fields, such as 'hasTouch' that did calls to Modernizr and similar.

So yes, this is possible.

Comment: Yeah, my point wasn't the environment checking itself, it was how to go about extending an existing directive. I've put a second example up to help illustrate.